# Microsoft Teams: Messaging extension on query result select item invoke and pastes thumbnail card on compose area at the same time on iOS

Tags: java, ios, iphone, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm building a Microsoft Teams bot with Compose Extension (Search extension) functionality. As soon as the user opens the search extension it fetches results from the backend. I'm using hero cards to show the result list. I have also added tap functionality into hero cards. That means when a user selects a result a backend invoke call will be triggered with some specific data and with that data I build an adaptive card.

This feature works well in Teams mac, web, and android apps. But with the native iOS app, not only triggers the invoke call but also pastes a thumbnail card on the Teams compose area.

I'm using iOS version 15.5 and Teams version 4.11.0

This is the response I'm building for the Search extension

```
{
    "composeExtension": {
        "type": "result",
        "attachmentLayout": "list",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.thumbnail",
                "content": {
                    "images": [
                        {
                            "url": "https:/localhost/93/937083/Public/img3-a68ff7.jpeg"
                        }
                    ],
                    "subtitle": "Subtitle",
                    "text": "Sample text",
                    "title": "Thumbnail card title"
                },
                "preview": {
                    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
                    "content": {
                        "buttons": null,
                        "images": [
                            {
                                "url": "https:/localhost/93/937083/Public/img3-a68ff7.jpeg"
                            }
                        ],
                        "subtitle": "Subtitle",
                        "tap": {
                            "type": "invoke",
                            "value": {
                                "type": "SELECT_CALLBACK",
                                "selectedItemId": 1001
                            }
                        },
                        "text": "Sample text",
                        "title": "Thumbnail card title"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot for reference:

[hero card on the compose area and adaptive card on the background built by invoked value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o86aq.jpg)

Comment: In your web,android you are not getting the Thumbnail card on compose area?
Are you not writing any code to preview the card on compose area?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT In my pc/mac, web and android I'm not getting a thumbnail card on compose area. Preview code is there as you can see from the json response but that's for the search result list. I don't want the thumbnail card to be thrown on the compose area.

Comment: We have tested this using following sample but in web and desktop Teams client also we are getting thumbnail card on the compose area.
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT please enable `tap` functionality and let me know what happens. I understand without tap functionality thumbnail card will be thrown to the compose area but with the `tap` action available it will invoke a background call.

Comment: After adding tap functionality also I am getting thumbnail card on the compose area.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT on all environments?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT after adding tap functionality do u get thumbnail card on iOS only or all environments?

Comment: I have checked in IOS,Android, Windows web and desktop Teams. For all environments I am getting thumbnail card on compose area.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT According to the GitHub example, the Preview is optional, if it includes a Tap, that will trigger the OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync event back on this bot. But in iOS, OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync is not triggered. Instead, it throws the thumbnail card on the compose area. Please check if it triggers OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync on iOS device or not. Please check the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiirn.png

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT This is the example I followed
Github example: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search

Comment: We have tested this on iOS 15.5 and Teams version 4.11.0.
OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync event is triggered at our end.
Could you please try to update the Teams version and check again.